# Google Cloud launcher not all network is listed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-launcher

I'm using Google cloud's "Cloud Launcher" to install a WordPress instance. However, in the network setting, I can only see some of my networks previously created, but not all of them. Can anybody explain what is the criteria for a network to show up here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Google Cloud Launcher is currently supported only on auto subnetwork networks and cannot be deployed in a custom subnet networks.

[Subnetworks Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/subnetworks#subnetwork_ip_ranges)